# Check if file exists, including on PATH

Tags: c, linux, file, path

Given a filename in C, I want to determine whether this file exists and has execute permission on it. All I've got currently is:

```
if( access( filename, X_OK) != 0 ) {
```

But this wont search the PATH for files and will also match directories (which I don't want). Could anyone please help?

Edit:

As an alternative, seeing as I'm running execvp() in a child process, is there a way to check the return value of execvp() and signal the parent process to die with an error message?

Comment: @diciu i know that. which is why I'm looking for a way to get C to search for the filename in these paths in the same way that bash does

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up having to set the FD_CLOEXEC flag on a new pipe and writing an error message through it after the exec if it had failed. I could then read the error message from the parent and determine whether exec was successful or not.

Thanks for your effort though guys, upvoted for the help

Answer (score 2):

This code's not quite what you want, as it simply blindly executes the first thing it comes to.   But you can modify the search code so that instead of calling `execve` you call `access` and then `stat` to find out if it's not a directory.  I think only the last function, `execvepath`, has to be replaced.

In the best Unix tradition, the code is "self-documenting" (i.e., undocumented).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#include "shellpath.h"

static void *malloc_check(const char *what, size_t n) {
  void *p = malloc(n);
  if (p == NULL) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Cannot allocate %zu bytes to %s\n", n, what);
    exit(2);
  }
  return p;
}

static char *strsave(const char *s, const char *lim) {
  if (lim == NULL)
    lim = s + strlen(s);
  char *p = malloc_check("save string", lim - s + 1);
  strncpy(p, s, lim-s);
  p[lim-s] = '\0';
  return p;
}

char ** shellpath(void) {
  const char *path = getenv("PATH");
  if (!path)
    path = "/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin";

  char **vector = // size is overkill
    malloc_check("hold path elements", strlen(path) * sizeof(*vector)); 
  const char *p = path;
  int next = 0;
  while (p) {
    char *q = strchr(p, ':');
    vector[next++] = strsave(p, q);
    p = q ? q + 1 : NULL;
  }
  vector[next] = NULL;
  return vector;
}

void freeshellpath (char *shellpath[]) {
  for (int i = 0; shellpath[i]; i++)
    free(shellpath[i]);
  free(shellpath);
}
unsigned maxpathlen(char *path[], const char *base) {
  unsigned blen = strlen(base);
  unsigned n = 0;
  for (int i = 0; path[i]; i++) {
    unsigned pn = strlen(path[i]);
    if (pn > n) n = pn;
  }
  return blen+n+1;
}



void execvepath(char *path[], const char *base, char *const argv[],
                char *const envp[])
{
  if (strchr(base, '/'))
    execve(base, argv, envp);
  else {
    size_t maxlen = maxpathlen(path, base)+1;
    char *buf = malloc_check("hold path", maxlen);
    for (int i = 0; path[i]; i++) {
      snprintf(buf, maxlen, "%s/%s", path[i], base);
      execve(buf, argv, envp);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey - thanks for your help. Tis seems much more complex than what I thought it'd be. Is there no way of running an exec function and having it return if the file doesn't exist?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following functions.
like..
the following codes contains some pseudo codes, but should be easy to implement

```
if the given path contains the current directory path,
like /root/a or ./abc, then
        return access( filename, X_OK) == 0;

Else - if the given path only contains the filename,
{
        getenv( "PATH" );
        while( iterate the directories in PATH )
        {
                if( search( PATH_directory, filename ) )
                {
                        // create the full path string with strcat, strcpy, and/or etc.
                        full_path = blabla

                        if( !is_directory( full_path ) && access( filename, X_OK ) == 0 )
                                return 1; // Yeah~~ We got it!!!
                }
        }

        return 0;   // Nah, I don't think there is any of such a file.
}
int is_directory( const char* path )
{
        struct stat file_info;
        return ( stat( path, &file_info ) == 0 ) ? S_ISDIR( file_info.st_mode ) : 0;
}


int search( const char* file_name, const char* path )
{
        struct dirent* dptr;
        DIR* dirp;

        if( (dirp = opendir( path )) == NULL )
                return 0;

        while( dptr = readdir( dirp ) )
        {
                if( strcmp( file_name, dptr->d_name ) == 0 )
                {
                        closedir( dirp );
                        return 1;
                }
        }

        closedir( dirp );    
        return 0;
}
```